# Как установить LAMP на Ubuntu 20.04 с флэшки

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, offline

Потребовалось развернуть web сервер на Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa. Опыта работы с ОС 0.5%. С VM нет доступа к интернет, некоторые программы ставил через дистрибутивы с https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal. Не могу найти дистрибутив для LAMP в сборке, так как с настройкой отдельных кусков в единый комплекс да на незнакомой ОС ожидаемо будут трудности. Подскажите где найти ?

Comment: Качни пакеты через `apt install -y --download-only <список пакетов>`, а потом забери их кэша в `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Самый простой способ.